Prove that a certain function is 2-lipschitzienne
I'm trying to prove the following proposition.
Prove that g:E×E→ℝ+, (x,y)→d(x,y) is a 2-lipschitz function.
The distance on ℝ+ is the usual distance
The distance on E×E is defined as d'((x,y),(x',y'))=max(d(x,y),d(x',y'))
With the properties of the usual distance, I proved that for any (x,y) and (x',y') in ExE:
abs(d(x,y)-d(x',y'))≤ d(x,x')+d(y,y')
But I don't see how to prove that d(x,x')+d(y,y') ≤ 2d'((x,y),(x',y')).
Thanks for your help

Do you see why $x + y \le 2\max(x,y)$?

Thanks for replying. Yes I do. But to me we are not in the same situation here. Are we ?

Ok, I think you misread the distance on $E\times E$ because that is definitely not a metric. It doesn't satisfy reflexivity.

As English is not my native language I might be confused with vocabulary but for me a metric must satisfy positivity, symetry and the triangle inequality. Which seems to be the case as d is a distance. Am I wrong ?

$d'((x, y), (x, y))$ is equal to the maximum of $d(x,y)$ with itself, which is not zero if $x \ne y$. Hence $d'$ is not zero even when the two arguments are equal, violating the definition of distance.

I was misreading indeed. Thank you so much ... d'((x,y),(x',y'))=max(d(x,x'),d(y,y')). And now it's easy.
